# How do I determine what zone .NET thinks my referenced DLL resides in?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I know that in the `security.config` file .NET defines what zones are available and what permissions are applicable to each zone: "FullTrust", "Internet", etc.

Suppose I have a DLL I am referencing in my application that resides at `\\someserver\somedir\library.dll`. How do I find out what zone .NET thinks this belongs to?

Is this a `TrustedZone`, `RestrictedZone`, `Internet` or `Intranet`?

What permissions are applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this to get the zone in the past

```
using System.Security.Policy;

...

Assembly myAssembly = ...;
var zone = myAssembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<Zone>();
Console.WriteLine(zone.SecurityZone);
```

Comment: perfect! Just what I was looking for!